# C# MySQL - MysqlDataReader with Switch not working :(

Tags: c#, mysql

I have current have this code for my C# windows application where it collects data from a table in my database and collects the 'NAME' corresponding with 'ID'. It isn't working, any tips?

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            for (counter = 0; counter >= 7; counter++)
            {
                string sq = "select * from products where ID='" + counter + "'";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sq, con);
                mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (mdr.Read())
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            Item1Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Item2Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Item3Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Item4Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Item5Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Item6Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Item7Btn.Text = mdr.GetString("NAME");
                            break;
                    }
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException rr)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured: " + rr.ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Nothing is working in this code for some reason :((((

Comment: Which thing is not working? Post error details in your question. `GetString("NAME")` possible to break execution if the column contains `DBNull.Value`, so watch out.

Comment: @mmushtaq: That should be fine

Comment: Do you have values in the table with ID's 1-7?

Comment: If you have ID value of 0 to 6 (or 1 to 7), `for (counter = 0; counter >= 7; counter++)` will return at least one empty query result (contains `DBNull`) & throwing error on `GetString`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Item1Btn.Text = mdr["NAME"];
```

Comment: Sorry, found the issue, i had a >= so the opperation wasn't running, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in the code. To begin with you need to concat the count as:
string sq = "select * from products where ID='" + **counter.ToString()** + "'";

Second the logic applied is inefficient,

You should have the SQL statement written as:
 **Select ID, Name from products where ID <=7**

Post this can use the reader and in switch case statement you can use the ID of the datarow instead of counter.

The last thing is you have set **counter =0** in the IF block.

Hope this is of some help.